# How to skip other middleware's if specific condition gets true in previous middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using asp.net core 6 WEBAPI project in which I have some custom middlewares listed below:

```
app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware1>();
app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware2>();
app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware3>();
```

Now there is one condition check I want to add in the `CustomMiddleware1` if that becomes true then I don't want to execute the other two middlewares.

Here is the code below:

```
public class CustomMiddleware1
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomMiddleware1(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path == "/login")
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Bypassing other middleware for login route");
        }
        else
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

it skips the other middleware but does not take to the Controller methods and directly returns 200 responses.

Comment: It's called "branching", see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline

Answer (score -1):

in your code yo have condition to match request path"/login" the middleware send direct response and does not pass the request to the controller.to resolve this you need to modify the middleware's logic so that it skips other middleware while still allowing the rest of the request pipeline to execute, including the controllers.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path == "/login")
        {
            // other middleware should be bypassed
            context.Items["BypassMiddleware"] = true;

            await _next(context);
        }
        else
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

check the flag and bypass CustomMiddleware2 and 3 logic:

```
public class CustomMiddleware2
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomMiddleware2(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Items.ContainsKey("BypassMiddleware"))
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        else
        {
            // other code
        }
    }
}
```

Apart from this approach you could try using `MapWhen` or `UseWhen` for Conditional Middleware Execution.

`MapWhen` branches the pipeline based on the result of a given predicate. Once branched, it does not rejoin the main pipeline.Use `MapWhen` if you want the request pipeline to branch off completely for certain conditions.

`UseWhen` is similar to `MapWhen` but after executing the branched pipeline, it rejoins the main pipeline.you can use this if you want to conditionally execute some middleware but then rejoin the main pipeline.